# Определение границ массива sqlReader

Tags: c#, sql

```
SqlDataReader sqlReader;
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(zapros, sqlConnection);
                sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                int i = 0;
                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    int r = 0;
                    while (sqlReader[r].ToString()!=null)
                    {
                        Arr[i, r] = sqlReader[r].ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show(Arr[i, r]);
                        r++;
                    }


                    i++;
                }
```

Как определить границу sqlReader[r] чтобы не вылетать за пределы массива

Comment: `sqlReader.FieldCount`

Comment: Спасибки большое

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov так мож ответом?

Answer (score 0):

У класса `SqlDataReader` есть свойство [FieldCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

И советую цикл `while` заменить на более удобный в данном случае `for`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sqlReader.FieldCount; i++)
{
    //sqlReader[i]
}
```